# collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status \\ CPP & HPP files

Tags: c++

I'm doing a project for one of my classes that requires me to have multiple CPP and HPP files. I feel like I defined all the classes correctly and set up the functions correctly. In the main file, I made a function to ask the user for some input. I then want to set the input of the user to an object so I can later manipulate it. However, I can't seem to figure out why I keep getting the following error.

Here is my code:

HEADER FILE

```
#ifndef CIRCLE_HPP
#define CIRCLE_HPP
#include "Rectangle.hpp"

class Circle{
    private:
        double radius;
    public:
        Circle();
        Circle(double radius);
        double getRadius();
        void setRadius(double setRadius);
        double calArea();
        double calCircumference();
        double calDiameter();
        bool compareWithRec(Rectangle rec);
};
#endif
```

CPP File

```
#include "Circle.hpp"
#include "Rectangle.hpp"
using namespace std;

static const double PI = 3.141592;
double area;
//constructor with no parameters
Circle::Circle(){
    radius = 1.0;
}

//constuctor with double parameter
Circle::Circle(double radius){
    this->radius = radius;
}

//accessor function
double Circle::getRadius(){
    return radius;
}

//mutator function 
void Circle::setRadius(double setRadius){
    radius = setRadius;
}

//member function for area
double Circle::calArea(){
    
    area = radius*radius*PI;
    return area;
}

//member function for circumference
double Circle::calCircumference(){
    double
    circumferance = 2*PI*radius;
    return circumferance; 
}

//member function for diameter
double Circle::calDiameter(){
    double
    diameter = 2*radius;
    return diameter; 
}

//member function to determine if recArea = calArea
bool Circle::compareWithRec(Rectangle rec){
    if(area == rec.calArea())
        return true;
    else   
        return false;
}
```

MAIN

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "Circle.hpp"
#include "Triangle.hpp"
#include "Rectangle.hpp"

void getAnswerRadius();




int main(){
    Circle obj;
    int userChoice;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "-= Main Menu: Choose a shape or exit =-" << endl;
    cout << "1. Circle" << endl;
    cout << "2. Triangle" << endl;
    cout << "3. Rectangle" << endl;
    cout << "0. Exit" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter an action: ";


    //loop to make user select options 1, 2, 3, or 0.
    do{
        cin >> userChoice;
        if(userChoice == 1){
            getAnswerRadius();
        }else if(userChoice == 2){
            cout << "two" << endl;
        }else if(userChoice == 3){
            cout << "three" << endl;
        }else if(userChoice == 0){
            cout << "Exit" << endl;
        }else{
            cout << "Hey! That doesnt look correct, please enter 1, 2, 3, or 0: ";
        }
    }while(userChoice != 1 && userChoice !=2 && userChoice != 3 && userChoice !=0);

    
    return 0;
}



//function ask for user input as well as collects user's input 
//function is responsible for setting radius (default is 1.0)
void getAnswerRadius(){
    char answer;
    double radiusCircle;
    Circle obj;
    cout << "Do you wish to enter the radius of the circle (Y/N): ";
    cin >> answer;
    if(answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y'){
        cout << "Please enter the value of radius of the circle: ";
        cin >> radiusCircle;
        Circle obj(radiusCircle);
    }else{
        cout << "error";
    }
}
```

Comment: Look are several lines up the error message you have posted.